# How to connect to the socket in the React-native?

Tags: react-native

I try to connect to the socket using the socket.io-client, but I get only the "SocketRocket: In debug mode. Allowing connection to any root cert." I checked different versions of the library and react-native and nothing happens. I thought that the address of the server is not correct but checked and it works as it should. I also created node js on localhost, connected to it and everything works, but does not connect to the remote server. "socket.io-client": "2.0.4", "react-native": "0.58.3".

```
import SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client'

componentDidMount(){

this.socket = SocketIOClient('wss://bitshares.openledger.info/ws',{
  'force new connection': true,
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionDelay: 10000,
    reconnectionDelayMax: 60000,
    reconnectionAttempts: 'Infinity',
    timeout: 10000,
    transports: ['websocket']
});
this.socket.connect();
// this.socket.send('123');
this.socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("CONNECTED")
});
this.socket.onopen=function(){
    console.log("onopen")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

var ws = new WebSocket('wss://bitshares.openledger.info/ws');

```
    ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log("onopen");
        // connection opened
    };

    ws.onmessage = (e) => {
        // a message was received
        console.log("onmessage",e.data);
    };

    ws.onerror = (e) => {
        // an error occurred
        console.log(e.message);
    };

    ws.onclose = (e) => {
        // connection closed
        console.log(e.code, e.reason);
    };
```